# Should I lock a variable in one thread if I only need it's value in other threads, and why does it work if I don't?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, opengl, sdl

<sub>I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859690/do-i-need-a-lock-when-only-a-single-thread-writes-to-a-shared-variable), but I believe my concerns are very different.</sub>

I recently created an SDL application, using threading and OpenGL.  I have one thread running in a loop, which continually updates the state of the objects I draw to the screen.  The states are very simple, it is just a boolean array (when the array value is true, I draw it, when it is false, I don't).

Currently, I have no mutex lock on any of my variables and everything is working just fine.  Even if only half of the state array was updated between a draw, the framerate is much higher (or at least equal to) the update rate, so it would be acceptable to have a half-updated state.

Now, I initially started working on a similar idea to this on an embedded system using interrupts.  Every once in a while, an interrupt would trigger, update the state array, and the execution would continue.  Now that I'm on a multi-core desktop, and updating the array simultaneously, I'm wondering why nothing bad is happening, since I am technically reading and writing to the same memory location *at the same time*.

- Is it just by chance, or is there a reason there's no memory access violations happening?
- If it is acceptable for the state of the variable to change just before, during, or just after the value is used, should I bother using a mutex lock?

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit: Additional information - the array is created dynamically, but when it is created/deleted, I do use a mutex (I figured accessing deleted memory wouldn't be looked kindly upon :P).

Comment: if the array doesn't change (like the size, position of items) there won't be any exception thrown.

Comment: @Dasiths yes, with respect to that, the array is static (position/size is constant when the threads are running).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, it's completely invalid (undefined behavior) to access memory like this without some synchronization.

In practice, it's moderately safe as long as:

1. Only one thread is writing and the others are all reading.
2. You don't care if the readers don't see some of the changes made until sometime later (possibly *much later* than the actual time they're written.
3. You don't care if the readers see *out-of-order* changes, i.e. they see some changes that were made later without seeing other changes that were made earlier.

Issues 2 and 3 are a non-issue on x86, but can occur on nearly every other real-world multi-core/SMP machine. You could mitigate them with some machine-specific asm (or compiler intrinsics) to insert *memory barriers* at appropriate points.

Comment: Don't forget about atomicity—if reading/writing quantities that are not machine word-sized (both smaller and larger), or if reading/writing misaligned values, you can see an inconsistent state for an object.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield what do you mean by inconsistent state?  Is that similar to out-of-order changes?

Comment: @Breakthrough: It means that in some conditions it could in theory be possible, on some machines, that some data has been changed, and some has not yet. For example, you could be writing the value `0xabcd` to a memory location that contains `0x1234` and another thread might read `0xab34`. In practice, this will not happen, unless you try very hard to _make it fail_. In practice, single (not R-M-W) operations up to pointer size are guaranteed, and besides that implementations are such that a cache line is read in, modified, and written back. So, you really need to do extra work to make it fail.

Comment: For your particular example, it does not matter at all, anyway. The worst thing to happen is that your application draws a few objects too many during one frame or another... so what.

Comment: @Damon thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to hear.  Considering the app runs *at least* 60 FPS, and I update the state around 30 times a second, it's no big deal.  Last thing, let's say I try to read the state just as a variable is being updated... What would happen if the computer was trying to simultaneously read *and* write to the same memory address?  It's not technically possible (since there's only one data and one address bus), but just wanted to see if you had any additional input.

Comment: @Breakthrough: If the machine is not SMP/multicore, there is *no way* for a simultaneous access to occur. Only one thread is actually scheduled, and everything is very simple. If the machine is SMP/multicore, the cpu/core making the write will detect that the cache line is shared with other cpus/cores and will invalidate them, stalling the other cpus/cores while the write happens and forcing them to refetch the entire cache line from main memory.

Comment: Also... Note that what I described is the way it works on x86. On pretty much any other arch, the cache state will just be inconsistent between cpus/cores. That's what causes issues 2 and 3 I described in my answer. An explicit barrier instruction is then required to force the cache invalidation.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that note.  I am okay with either issues (2) or (3) occurring, since the timing isn't a large issue here.  I just wanted to be assured that any memory access violations or exceptions wouldn't be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean array elements are can be set/read with an atomic operation, there is not need for a mutex.  You need a mutex to protect a structure to make sure that it stays consistent.  Since your booleans are independent there is no problem.

Comment: The set of booleans forms a non-atomic structure, however. But in this usage scenario I'd say, the OP is safe. OP may also read up on "lock free algorithms".

Comment: Exactly, a set of booleans would form a non-atomic structure if there were some consistency requirement on them, and you had to change multiple pieces of the set without being interrupted in the process.