# OpenGL multiple threads, variable handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have written an OpenGL program which runs in the following way:

```
Main:
- Initialize SDL
- Create thread which has the OpenGL context:
    - Renderloop
        - Set camera (view) matrix with glUniform.
        - glDrawElements() .... etc.
        - Swapbuffers();
- Main SDL loop handling input events and such.
    - Update camera matrix of type glm::mat4.
```

This is how I pass my camera object to the class that handles opengl.

```
Camera *cam = new Camera();
gl.setCam(cam);
```

where

```
void setCam(Camera *camera) {
    this->camera = camera;
}
```

For rendering in the opengl context thread, this happens:

```
glm::mat4 modelView = camera->view * model;
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader->bindUniform("modelView"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelView));
```

In the main program where my SDL and other things are handles I then recompute the view matrix. This his working fine without me using any mutex locks. Is this correct?

On the other hand, I add objects to my scene by an "upload queue" and in this case I have to mutex lock my upload queue vector (vector class type) when adding items to it or else the program crashes.

In summary: I recompute my matrix in a different thread and then use it in the opengl thread without any mutex lock. Why is this working?

**Edit:**
I think my question is similar to what was asked here:

1) [Should I lock a variable in one thread if I only need it's value in other threads, and why does it work if I don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935208/should-i-lock-a-variable-in-one-thread-if-i-only-need-its-value-in-other-thread?rq=1), only in my case it is even more simple with only one matrix being changed.

2) [Do I need a lock when only a single thread writes to a shared variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859690/do-i-need-a-lock-when-only-a-single-thread-writes-to-a-shared-variable)

Comment: There is no `gl.setCam` function in OpenGL. Or SDL for that matter. Without knowing what `gl.setCam` does or how it treats its pointer argument, there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. Updated the code with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this working?

Who says that it is?

The rule of thumb in multithreaded code is really quite simple: if your multithreaded code is not *provably thread-safe*, then it is wrong by default.

Mutexes and other synchronization structures allow you to prove that your code works. Without that proven functionality, you're just rolling the dice. Maybe you're just lucky on that machine. Maybe if you reboot your computer, it'll stop working. Maybe if you sneeze it'll break.

Just because something *happens* to function as you intend doesn't mean that it works. Only that you get away with it, much like a thief not being caught by the police doesn't mean that they won't catch him if they try it again.

You can choose to rely on unproven threading code if you want. Or you can do things right and not have to worry.

---

> which as I understand would behave the same as if I where to do

No, it won't.

In your first case, you are passing a pointer to a stack object. That stack object will be destroyed when the scope ends. Any attempts to *use* that pointer for anything from that point on will cause badness.

In your second case, you are passing a pointer to a newly heap-allocated object. That object will be destroyed when *you* destroy it. Someone must have the responsibilty for deleting this object. Presumably when you pass that pointer to `gl.setCam`, the `gl` object is taking on that responsibility to destroy it at the proper time.

This is standard C++ stuff here; it has nothing to do with OpenGL, multiple threads, anything. This is all about the concept of ownership; you passed memory that was owned by the stack to a function that was expecting to claim ownership of it. You made a promise you couldn't keep. Hence, boom.

Comment: I am aware of this. This is not relevant for the question. I should not have included this information as I see now that it only creates confusion. I have edited my question keeping only the relevant information now.

Comment: I am reading answer from this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935208/should-i-lock-a-variable-in-one-thread-if-i-only-need-its-value-in-other-thread?rq=1). Which says:
1) Only one thread is writing and the others are all reading.

This is what I am doing. I never change the camera matrix in the opengl context, I only read from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concerns where that a mutex lock/unlock would be an expensive call to have in the rendering loop.

Comment: @toeplitz: You shouldn't be throwing data at the rendering system during the render loop. You should be throwing data at a special system, which will feed data to the render loop at the speed that it wants. Your thread sync stuff goes there. The most effective way to have provable thread sync is to minimize inter-thread communication. Put it all in as few places as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know of any references or examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this working?

I don't know, my crystal orb is broken and you didn't give us your code. Since OpenGL has no camera and you use a Camera class I think you might have some copies going around (possibly leaking memory).

Comment: The uniform view matrix is what is being used which is a part of the camera class. I calculate the modelview matrix like this: glm::mat4 modelView = camera->view * model;

Comment: Added more details to my post.